# Retorno da função main

Tags: c, c++, return

Estudando C/C++ aprendi que colocamos o `return 0` no final da função `main()` para indicar que o programa funcionou corretamente, caso isso ocorra. Mas caso isso não ocorra, um valor diferente de 0 será retornado pela `main()`. O que esse valor indica especificamente? Acredito que não seja um número aleatório.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assim como é possível passar argumentos para o código pela função `main()` através do parâmetro `argv` (com auxilio do `argc`) e estes dados vêm de quem chamou o executável, você também pode retornar um dado para quem chamou. Geralmente quem chamou é o sistema operacional (por ação de algum usuário ou *script* que cuida disto) e é ele que receberá esta informação para ser usada de alguma forma, por exemplo um *script* pode pegar isto e decidir o que fazer.

O número que vai retornar é definido por você mesmo para sua aplicação e deve documentar bem isto para quem for chamá-la possa usar este resultado para alguma coisa de acordo com a semântica que você quis dar e que faça algum sentido. Em geral cada número indica algum erro específico que deu, de acordo com sua documentação.

Mas é um engano que você precisa usar o `return 0`, se não fizer isto haverá o retorno de 0 de forma implícita, pelo menos isto vale para todos os compiladores mais conhecidos.

E tem um outro detalhe, quase todas as vezes que for retornar um erro o fará através, direta ou indiretamente, da função [`exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) ou algo semelhante, já que isto ocorrerá em outra parte do código que não a `main()` e deverá encerrar imediatamente.

Comment: É _standard_ em C11/C18 não precisar retornar valor em `main`?

Comment: Sim, até onde eu sei desde C99.

Comment: Achei em 5.1.2.2.3 do rascunho "_reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0._"

Answer (score 5):

O número retornado só faz sentido no contexto do programa que você criou. Se você estiver ciente de um possível erro, você pode colocar `return 1` em um ponto, e `return 2` em outro. Se o programa eventualmente falhar, fica mais fácil de traçar qual foi o motivo do erro pelo código retornado.

Comment: Mas fora de contexto, existe algum significado para ele?